# Sequelizejs get fields from relation table into association belongsToMany

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using `Sequelizejs@4.37.6` on NodeJs for Postgre database with the below schema:

`players` Schema

```
id
first_name
last_name
...
status
```

`sports` Schema

```
id
name
...
status
```

`player_sports` Schema

```
id
player_id
sport_id
rating
trophies
```

My Associations are

```
Player.belongsToMany(Sport, {through: 'player_sports', foreignKey: 'player_id'});
PlayerSport.hasOne(Player, {foreignKey: 'id'});
PlayerSport.hasOne(Sport, {foreignKey: 'id'});
```

I am querying all players with sports as below

```
Player.findAll({
    include: ['sports']
});
```

Everything is working as expected but I also want to have `rating` and `trophies` fields in the relation, please suggest a way to get those either in player or `player.sports`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `rating`, `trophies` from `player` like this:

`player.sports.player_sports.trophies`

`player.sports.player_sports.rating`

if you get an error try to change `PlayerSport` associations to this one:

```
PlayerSport.belongsTo(Player, {foreignKey: 'player_id'});
PlayerSport.belongsTo(Sport, {foreignKey: 'sport_id'});
```